# OSS Server Monitoring Software -- Which is right for me?

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring, opennms, zenoss

I'm trying to plot the course for my organization and am currently looking at (not exclusively so, but so far research leads to these):

Zenoss

Nagios

OpenNMS

Our requirements is that this must be freely licensed, support SNMP/WMI monitoring, as well as alternative monitoring for situations where firewalls block SNMP/WMI (eg: webservice, TCP, agent)

At a minimum we're looking for graphical network map with uptime statistics, traffic stats, service availability, and hardware monitoring.

We have a custom agent that collects very detailed/granular hardware information on our supported systems , and will be making efforts to tie this into whatever NMS we choose. That sort of piqued my interest on OpenNMS as we might be able to directly forward our data to our NMS system without a lot of fidgeting.

Can someone help elaborate what I can do with Zenoss vs nagios? Any product will be likely used as the "free' version.

I suppose VMWare/Virtualization support for monitoring VMs is something that should be considered as well.

Trying to digest a lot of information and any help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great comparison of quite a few network/server/services monitoring tools here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems

Comment: thanks.. That has actually made me at least go out and try OpenNMS  -- I have no love for java but the TCP thing seems to good to completely discount it before giving it a whirl

Answer (score 0):

CentreON is a great solution. it has a opensource version and a full commercial version.

http://www.centreon.com/